# Not able to display view in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Use the following code I am not able to display any HTML. I do not receive any error in the console any error. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

---

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="KanbanBoard" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <script src="libs/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>
    <script src="app/boards/boardsController.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

app.js

```
   'use strict';
    var app = angular.module('KanbanBoard', ['ngRoute']);

    (function () {

        app.config(function ($routeProvider) {

            $routeProvider.when("/boards", {
                controller: "BoardsController",
                templateUrl: "/app/boards/boardsView.html"
            });

            $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: "/boards" });

        });

    })();
```

controller.js

```
'use strict';
(function () {
    app.controller('BoardsController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.users;
        this.users = [
                    {
                        id: 0,
                        email: 'a@a.com',
                        name: 'A',
                        surname: 'B',
                        initials: 'AB',
                        boards: [
                            {
                                id: 0,
                                title: 'Welcome Board',
                                description: 'Board sample',
                                isArchived: false,
                            },
                            {
                                id: 1,
                                title: 'Project X',
                                description: 'Project X description',
                                isArchived: false,
                            }
                        ]
                    }
        ];
        $scope = this.users;
    }]);
})();
```

---

boardView.html

```
<div ng-controller="BoardsController as boardsCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="user in boardsCtrl.users">
        {{user.name + " " + user.surname}}
        <ul>
            <li></li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would personally put the `angular.module('KanbanBoard', ['ngRoute']);` inside the self executing!! Theres no reason to have it outside

Comment: Do you have a `ng-app` attribute defined. Also `$scope = this.users;` is very strange line. Did you mean `$scope.users = users`?

Comment: Also, have you put the `ng-app` attribute there?

Comment: yes ng-app is in place in index.html, please look edited answer

Comment: `$scope = this.users;` in controller overwrites your `$scope`. Try to use `$scope.users = this.users`.

Comment: your angular version.

Comment: I have done a [plnker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jdNrkHsfK9vZTkdhzQZF?p=preview) for you, if you lay out your angular app like I have, you will find it so much easier to make proper modular apps. Plus its cleaner to look at and read IMHO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the body of your webpage it seems that you are missing `ng-view`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="KanbanBoard" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>

    <div ng-view></div> <!--this is required.-->

    <script src="libs/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>
    <script src="app/boards/boardsController.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

#### From the documentation:

> ngView is a directive that complements the $route service by including the rendered template of the current route into the main layout (index.html) file. Every time the current route changes, the included view changes with it according to the configuration of the $route service.

Comment: Not only that, when I did a plnker I took out the `BoardsController as bc` and it worked.... maybe something there was wrong

Comment: Yeah maybe OP is using older version of angular.

Answer (score 0):

You missed adding the Boardview.html with controller on your index.html

It could be done inline or by using ng-include:

```
<div ng-include="boardView.html"></div>
```